# Find dictionary keys using values from a list

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

```
diz = {'KTOP': 1194654, 'WDFR': 1217, 'WKLJ': 1306, 'MLKJ': 2958}

list = [1217, 1306, 2958, 1194654]
```

I'm looking for a sorted list that contains ONLY the keys of my dictionary that have the values == to the int of my list.

How do i get it?

I have sorted the values of the dictionary but now I don't how to get the keys sorted using the list of values.

I need an output like this:

```
lOutput = [ 'WDFR', 'WKLJ', 'MLKJ' , 'KTOP' ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
diz = {'KTOP': 1194654, 'WDFR': 1217, 'WKLJ': 1306, 'MLKJ': 2958}
l1 = [1217, 1306, 2958, 1194654]
d = {v:k for k, v in diz.items()}
new_list = [d[k] for k in l1 if k in d]
```

Prints:

```
>>> new_list
['WDFR', 'WKLJ', 'MLKJ', 'KTOP']
```

---

Above code will fail if values are repeated in the dict(which is usually the case as only keys are unqiue in dict not the values.)

Use:

First create a list `d` which contains `key` from the `diz` only if `value(=diz[key])` is in the `l1`.
Now create a map `sort_key` from value to its index in l1, the index of value in l1 will be used to sort the `d`.
Now sort `d` using key from `sort_key`.

```
d = [k for k, v in diz.items() if v in set(l1)]
sort_key = {k: v for v, k in enumerate(l1)}
new_list = list(sorted(d, key = lambda x: sort_key[diz[x]]))
```

Prints

```
>>> new_list
['WDFR', 'WKLJ', 'MLKJ', 'KTOP']
```

Answer (score 1):

For using `Inbuilt-python` functionality you can refer to  [Amit Vikram Singh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67192166/14867730) answer. For other method you can refer to this method.

**LOGIC:**

`Numpy` inbuilt `argsort` will result sorted argument which you can use to sort keys.

```
np.argsort(list(diz.values()))
```

**CODE:**

```
import numpy as np

diz = {'KTOP': 1194654, 'WDFR': 1217, 'WKLJ': 1306, 'MLKJ': 2958}
keys = list(diz.keys())
print([keys[i] for i in np.argsort(list(diz.values()))])
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
['WDFR', 'WKLJ', 'MLKJ', 'KTOP']
```

Comment: I think yours only is the correct answer as mine can fail if values are repeated.

Comment: @AmitVikramSingh Yaa you right but instead of creating d as `dict` object please type to create a `list` of  two value this can resolve this bug

Comment: Two value of  `d as list` can be any format as `[ [v, k] for k, v in diz.items()]`

Answer (score 0):

You can cross-check the values in the dictionary with the items in the list. I'd also highly recommend to use a variable name other than the built-in `list`.

```py
diz = {'KTOP': 1194654, 'WDFR': 1217, 'WKLJ': 1306, 'MLKJ': 2958}
mylist = [1217, 1306, 2958, 1194654]

values = set(mylist)
output = [key for key, value in diz.items() if value in values]
```

Note that I saved the list items in a set, which allows fast (i.e. **O(1)**) lookup.

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to get your desired output with this one liner:

`[key for key, value in diz.items() if value in mylist]`

Answer (score 0):

```
diz = {'KTOP': 1194654, 'WDFR': 1217, 'WKLJ': 1306, 'MLKJ': 2958}
list = [1217, 1306, 2958, 1194654]

def find_the_same(list, set):
    listReady = []
    for key, value in set.items():
        if value in list:
            listReady.append(key)
    return listReady

print(find_the_same(list, diz))
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering! Could you explain how and why your code works and solves the question? Code-only answers are often difficult to understand for inexperienced users.

Comment: I made a simple loop and turned it into a definition

listReady = []
for key, value in diz.items():
    if value in list:
        listReady.append(key)
        print(listReady)